# SQL Bulk copy with referential integrity

Tags: sqlbulkcopy

My requirement is to be able to bulk insert data to multiple table. (Having foreign key constraints)  I won't get the foreign keys till I submit the batch to the parent table. how to achieve this using bulk copy?
i cannot use linked servers or openrowset due to policy constraints.

Answer (score 1):

you may be able to get away with turning off the constraints temporarily during the bulk load.